# OpenVPN configuration

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, ip, openvpn

Preamble: *I am lucky to have an IP subnet which has real IPs, so no NAT*. I have a network from 1.2.3.0 to 1.2.3.128.

I have a Debian server with an eth0 interface say 1.2.4.9. Now I want to have an openVPN to bridge to this interface and give addresses to clients say from address 1.2.3.80 to 1.2.3.90.

Do I need some br0 interfaces?

All the tutorials introduce NATing at some point, but I do not need it.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that's actually covered in the [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html) documentation and should be pretty trivial to do. You're going to need to alter the scripts provided for your own settings. Since you have 128 IP addresses, I believe your netmask is 25 - [from here](http://net.berkeley.edu/DNS/ip4netmask.shtml)

From that we can derive a fair amount of information on your system - I used [this IP address calculator](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=1.2.4.9&mask1=25&mask2=) to work this out and it gives the following information

```
Address:   1.2.4.9               00000001.00000010.00000100.0 0001001
Netmask:   255.255.255.128 = 25  11111111.11111111.11111111.1 0000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.127             00000000.00000000.00000000.0 1111111
=>
Network:   1.2.4.0/25            00000001.00000010.00000100.0 0000000 (Class A)
Broadcast: 1.2.4.127             00000001.00000010.00000100.0 1111111
HostMin:   1.2.4.1               00000001.00000010.00000100.0 0000001
HostMax:   1.2.4.126             00000001.00000010.00000100.0 1111110
Hosts/Net: 126
```

Plugging those numbers into the steps given in openvpn's documentation would get you started.

You will need to create a startup and shutdown file for the server bridge to use a bridged interface. You will also need bridge utils. While I've included the essential steps, RTFM too in case I missed anything
    #!/bin/bash

```
#################################
# Set up Ethernet bridge on Linux
# Requires: bridge-utils
#################################

# Define Bridge Interface
br="br0"

# Define list of TAP interfaces to be bridged,
# for example tap="tap0 tap1 tap2".
tap="tap0"

    # Define physical ethernet interface to be bridged
    # with TAP interface(s) above.
    eth="eth0"
    eth_ip="1.2.4.9"
    eth_netmask="255.255.255.128"
    eth_broadcast="1.2.4.127"

    for t in $tap; do
        openvpn --mktun --dev $t
    done

    brctl addbr $br
    brctl addif $br $eth

    for t in $tap; do
        brctl addif $br $t
    done

    for t in $tap; do
        ifconfig $t 0.0.0.0 promisc up
    done

    ifconfig $eth 0.0.0.0 promisc up

    ifconfig $br $eth_ip netmask $eth_netmask broadcast $eth_broadcast
```

and the shutdown file as per the documentation - note the change in eth_ip, eth_netmask and eth_broadcast

You need to alter your openvpn configuration file to comment out the line reading `dev tun` and add a new line reading `dev tap0` 
and replace the line reading `server` and replace it with `server-bridge 1.2.4.9 255.255.255.128 1.2.3.80 1.2.3.90` - the IP address of the server, the netmask as per that calculator and the start and end of the IP address range you want.